# How do you use printf from Assembly?

Tags: assembly, include, x86

I have an MSVC++ project set up to compile and run assembly code.

In main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void go() ;

int main()
{
  go() ; // call the asm routine
}
```

In go.asm:

```
.586
.model flat, c
.code

go PROC
  invoke puts,"hi"
  RET
go ENDP

end
```

But when I compile and run, I get an error in go.asm:

> error A2006: undefined symbol : puts

How do I define the symbols in `<stdio.h>` for the .asm files in the project?

Comment: You have to somehow link to your C standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have.

It works!!

```
.586
.model flat,c

printf PROTO C :VARARG  ; The secret sauce.. a prototype of printf

.data
msgHello1 BYTE "GREETINGS AND WELCOME TO EARTH!",0 

.code

go PROC
  push OFFSET msgHello1
  call printf
  add esp, 4 ;  Stack cleaning
  RET
go ENDP

end
```

- ["stack cleaning"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)
- [How to call variadic argument function such as printf](https://cmlmail.csie.ntu.edu.tw/pipermail/assembly/Week-of-Mon-20061204/000042.html)

Comment: where is the definition of printf ? If you are using C library, it needs to be defined as extern. I am guessing that crash has something to do with Calling convetion. Use ollydbg to debug ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/86816) explains it better than I can.

Roughly put, the assembler cannot find the symbol (function) in `go.asm`. You have to tell it its an external symbol.

The linked article approaches building a mixed-code app from the point of view of using assembly as the main language including running the `main` routine. If you're using a `C` based main routine, much of what is done is unnecessary, you should just need:

> Assemble the assembly module with /Mx
>   to preserve the case of nonlocal
>   names. If using MASM version 6.0 or
>   later, use /Cx to preserve the case of
>   nonlocal names.

and:

> Include the statement .MODEL , c in the assembly module to
>   ensure that C naming and calling
>   conventions are used and that the
>   modules use the same default segments.
>   The  will be small, medium,
>   compact, or large.

and `EXTERN` directives for each function you wish to call in the format: `EXTERN printf:proc`.